# Snowflake: Tree Structure (Hierarchical Data and its count)

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, hierarchical-data

How do I iterate over all the rows in a table in Snowflake and pass it to a Python function without using pandas?

I have a Snowflake table with following columns:
`EmployeeID, EmployeeName, DirectReportID, DirectReportName, InDirectReportID, InDirectReportName`. I have the tree structure ready using `SQL recursive CTEs`. I have tried `CONNECT_BY` but that doesn't give the depth of the table it goes from top to bottom (until EmployeeID instead of all people below a specific EmployeeID).I want to apply a Python DFS fn (that fn is also ready) to every row in my table. Is there a way I can achieve this using Python Stored Procedure in Snowflake? Is there a way to achieve tail recursion in this scenario?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Done. Edited and the first part is my question. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

See [Dealing with Parent-Child SQL Queries](https://jsimonbi.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/dealing-with-parent-child-sql-queries-pt2/) for an example of querying for descendants of a specific node in a recursive CTE.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not need a SQL Query. I want to connect my SQL table and pass it to a Python function for tail recursion so that I get the tree.